# Access custom column (alias) in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, alias, where-clause

I'm having a bit of trouble because I can't access a custom column in the Where clause. In many attempts, it is only possible on the `HAVING` clause (slower and something I want to avoid). Is it possible to access on `WHERE` clause? I give an example:

```
SELECT (...) IF(table1.x="bla",table1.date,table2.date) as date
FROM (...)
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)>1321401600
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to perform the timestamp check on both your tables in that case. `(where table1.date > x)` and also on your join `(join table2 on table2.date > x)`

Comment: Daniel, with the IF clause inside WHERE ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an alias in your `WHERE` then you can wrap the query in a `SELECT` to use the alias:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT (...) IF(table1.x="bla",table1.date,table2.date) as date
   FROM (...)
) x
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)>1321401600
```

Comment: That code isn't similar to Having clause? At least it seems slow too :(

Comment: If you run the query without the `WHERE` how does it perform?

Comment: he will get every register (takes about 20 seconds). Same amount of time as my Having clause (gets every register and then only shows the ones with timestamp>1321401600). Thought it could take about 0,5secs xD

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to perfom the timestamp check on both your tables in that case.

E.g.

```
SELECT ... FROM table1
     JOIN table2 ON table2.date > x
WHERE table1.date > x
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter how you rewrite it, I think your server is going to find it difficult to optimise that particular expression, so you will always find that your query is slow, but I guess the best thing to do is to test everyone's answers and see which one is the fastest. So with that in mind, here's my suggestion:

```
WHERE (table1.x = "bla" AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(table1.date) > 1321401600)
  OR (table1.x != "bla" AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(table2.date) > 1321401600)
```

Comment: what if i make 2 querys? one using table1.date and table2.date and then in my PHP try to do the rest... you think it is faster?

Comment: I don't know of any way to tell without actually testing it, which is your job.